# Inline PHP Send Mail not working

Tags: php

PHP isn't my strength and when I was asked to implement a modal newsletter subscription popup I cringed because I knew I was going to have to use PHP.  I have scoured the internet all day trying various things, but I cannot seem to get anything to work and I am really hoping that someone will be able to point me in the right direction.  It is super simple, I only need a name and email address which is then sent to an account I specify.  I am sure this is really basic, but with my lack of experience with PHP I am totally lost as to where I am going wrong.  My code is below.

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="my@emailaddress.com";
    $subject="Newsletter Subscription";
    $senderName=$_POST["name"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["email"];

    $mailBody="Name: $senderName\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\nThis is a test!";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $senderName <$senderEmail>");

    header('Location:http://www.urltoredirect.com/');
}
?>

<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="sendmail.php">
        <div class="rbm_input_txt">
            <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="rbm_input_txt">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="rbm_form_submit">
            <button type="submit" class="rbm_btn_x_out_shtr">subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I save the file as sendmail.php and upload to my server.  When I fill out the form, the page just reloads, it isn't redirecting to the URL specified and I am not receiving any email.  I suspect the issue is in the send mail and once that is sorted, the redirect will work.  Can anyone see anything obvious that I am missing?

EDIT: Added the name attribute to my code as suggested below.  Issue is still unresolved.

Comment: Your `<input>` fields require `name` attributes that correspond to your `$_POST[]` variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking to see if `$_POST['submit']` is truthy, but your form never actually sets that value. There are two changes you can make to fix this:

1. In order for the `submit` key to be present in your request, you need to assign it to a field in your form. You'll likely want to add it to the submit button, which can be done by simply adding the name parameter to your submit button:

   ```
   <button name="submit" type="submit" class="rbm_btn_x_out_shtr">subscribe</button>
   ```
2. Even with the above change, `$_POST['submit']` will still evaluate to false since its value will be empty. (You can see this in the rules for [boolean conversions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).) You can get around this by checking to see if its set, rather than if it's truthy:

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
   ```

Alternatively, you could just look for a different field such as `name` or `email`, since you know both of those fields will be set on submit.

Comment: Yes!  I made that change, the redirect worked and I got the email.  Thank you so much for your assistance!  I don't really understand why, though I suspect a trip to the PHP documentation for isset() will shed some light on that.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to experiment with your script, I'd recommend adding a var_dump($_POST) or print_r($_POST) to see how adding the name to the submit button changed the request. I also added a link to boolean conversions that might help clarify the need for isset.

Answer (score 1):

there must be name in tags

```
  <div class="rbm_input_txt"><input type="name" placeholder="name" name="name" required><input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email``" required
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did that but it still didn't redirect, nor did I receive the email so I don't think that is all that is wrong.